# I want to run stored procedure in a loop

Tags: db2

I want to run sp in a loop .
I am using db2.
For ex if there are 10 rows in my table and 8 rows contain status as approved ,I want those 8 rows to be executed 1 by 1 through my sp .

I have used this method

```
declare @v_count INT;
declare @row_count INT;

declare @v_actorCNUM      CHAR(10); 
declare @v_sessID      CHAR(32);
declare @v_taskID      SMALLINT;
declare @v_dest_citrusSCID   INTEGER;  
declare @v_src_citrusSCID  INTEGER;
declare @v_CtrCnum         CHAR(10);
declare @v_dest_security_grp_nm  varchar(100);  
declare @v_src_security_grp_nm  varchar(100);

SET @v_count=1;
 DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE csc_trfr
(   
  Row_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
 CNTRCTR_CNUM CHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
              DEST_CSC_NM CHAR(30) ,
              SRC_CSC_NM CHAR(30) ,
              DEST_GRP_NM VARCHAR(100) ,
              SRC_GRP_NM VARCHAR(100) ,
              USR_LST_UPDT_ID CHAR(10) 
  ) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT lOGGED;
 insert into       session.csc_trfr                                                 (cntrctr_cnum,dest_csc_nm,src_csc_nm,dest_grp_nm,src_grp_nm,usr_lst_updt_id)
  select    cntrctr_cnum,dest_csc_nm,source_csc_nm,dest_grp_nm,src_grp_nm,usr_lst_updt_id from citrus.cntrctr_csc_trfr where trfr_status='Approved';

    select count(*) into @row_count from citrus.cntrctr_csc_trfr where  trfr_status='Approved';

while @v_count<=@row_count

  BEGIN


 SET @v_actorCNUM=select usr_lst_updt_id from session.csc_trfr order by    row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only;
 SET @v_taskID=166;
  set @v_dest_citrusSCID =select citrus_suprt_id from citrus.citrus_suprt_cntr where citrus_suprt_nm=(select DEST_CSC_NM from session.csc_trfr order by row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only );
set @v_src_citrusSCID=select citrus_suprt_id from citrus.citrus_suprt_cntr where citrus_suprt_nm=(select SRC_CSC_NM from session.csc_trfr order by row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only );
 set @v_CtrCnum=select cntrctr_cnum from session.csc_trfr order by row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only;
 set @v_dest_security_grp_nm =select  DEST_GRP_NM from session.csc_trfr order by row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only;
set @v_src_security_grp_nm=select  DEST_GRP_NM from session.csc_trfr order by row_id offset @v_count rows fetch next 1 rows only;
 call citrus.BAC020_cntrctrCSCTrfr(@v_actorCNUM,'',@v_taskID,@v_dest_citrusSCID,@v_src_citrusSCID,@v_CtrCnum,@v_dest_security_grp_nm,@v_src_security_grp_nm,?,?,?);
  @v_count=@v_count+1;
 end
```

I have name script as test.sql and executing script like :
db2 -tvf test.sql
but I am getting sql error.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "declare @v_actorCNUM      CHAR" was found
following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601

error is same for all variables.

My code is count the rows in cntctr_csc_trfr table where transfer status is approved .and then I am putting those rows in temp table .For each row in temp table I want to run stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed"? Could you also add some comments in your code of what you try to do? And try to use "v_actorCNUM" without the @ sign.

Comment: Henrik I have added comment below what my code is exactly doing.

Comment: I have removed @ sign still it is giving error

Comment: What tool are you using to create the SP? What is the statement terminator? Where is the actual CREATE PROCEDURE part of the statement?

Comment: tool is db2 
statement terminator -> ;

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. May be you could study some of the samples provided in the manual and build your code from simple to complex step by step.

Comment: With "tool" I meant something like IBM Data Studio (free to download and use). It has a built-in editor with syntax support. For the statement terminator there is the ";" to end each statement within the Stored Procedure, you also need something to end the SP itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
Here is an example :

```
use database1
```

go
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @RequestCode nvarchar(50)
Declare column_cursor Cursor For 
    select columnName from table_name
OPEN column_cursor
    Fetch Next From column_cursor into @RequestCode 
    While @@Fetch_Status=0 Begin
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[stored_procedure_name]     @RequestCode 
Fetch Next From column_cursor Into @RequestCode 
    End
    Close column_cursor
    Deallocate column_cursor